# How to count between no of days between two dates month wise in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Two Date in SQL sever which overlap in two month i want to find how many days over lap in each month. 
For example:

```
Start date is : 26-Sep-2012
End Date is : 10-Oct-2012

Sept- 5 days
October - 10 days
```

along with the list of date of each month.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @start datetime;
declare @end datetime;
set @start = '20120926';
set @end = '20121010';

SELECT (DAY(DATEADD (m, 1, DATEADD(d, 1 - DAY(@start), @start))-1)
        - DAY(@start) + 1) AS DaysLeftStart,
        DAY(@end) AS DaysEnd
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/4441/0

Comment: almost - there should be a count of all the months in between as well.. i think.

Comment: I'm not sure: _"...overlap in two month, i want to find how many days over lap in each month"_ even though, he can join a calendar table for each day between then or use above approach to find the days in each full month between (just omit the `- DAY(@start) + 1`).

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME, @end DATETIME;

SELECT @start = '20120926', @end = '20121010';

;WITH c(d) AS
(
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @start, @end)+1)
    DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)-1, @start)
    FROM sys.all_columns
) 
SELECT 
  [date] = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, d), 0), 
  [days] = COUNT(*)
FROM c GROUP BY DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, d)
UNION ALL SELECT d, NULL FROM c;
```

Results:

```
date                        days
-----------------------     -----
2012-09-01 00:00:00.000     5
2012-10-01 00:00:00.000     10
2012-09-26 00:00:00.000     NULL
2012-09-27 00:00:00.000     NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000     NULL
2012-09-29 00:00:00.000     NULL
2012-09-30 00:00:00.000     NULL
2012-10-01 00:00:00.000     NULL
2012-10-02 00:00:00.000     NULL
2012-10-03 00:00:00.000     NULL
2012-10-04 00:00:00.000     NULL
2012-10-05 00:00:00.000     NULL
2012-10-06 00:00:00.000     NULL
2012-10-07 00:00:00.000     NULL
2012-10-08 00:00:00.000     NULL
2012-10-09 00:00:00.000     NULL
2012-10-10 00:00:00.000     NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2010/07/19/calendar-table-and-datetime-functions.aspx) you can find some detail about creating a calendar table. You can use it to perform such query:

```
SELECT CalendarMonth, count(*) day_num 
FROM dbo.Calendar 
WHERE CalendarDate  between @start_date and @end_date;
```